# How to Clone from GitHub

Tags: github, cloning

I'm new using GitHub. I'm trying to clone my first file from a users repo.
I keep receiving this error:

`Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

When I check to verify the public key is attached to my GitHub account, by using this command:

`ssh-add -1`

I get this error:
`The agent has no identities.`

I've also tried this:
`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

in which it tells me:
 `Identity added`

I also ensured that my laptop's SSH key was added to my GitHub account. What steps am I missing?

I've scanned the internet – I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can use the https protocol to clone i.e https://github.com/Organization/repo.git you wouldn't need the key pair for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can clone a github repository in 2 ways. You can choose the type while cloning the repository.

[image: See the highlighted part in image]

1. HTTPS

   `git clone https://github.com/flyway/flyway.git`

You may need to provide username/password if it is a private repository.

2. SSH

   `git clone git@github.com:flyway/flyway.git`

You need to setup ssh keys in your PC and update in your github account.

Read more about

[Adding SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)

[Which remote URL should I use?](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/)

Answer (score 1):

Try cloning repository by https link `git clone https://github.com/github_user_name/repository_name`

And you can add the SSH key manually into your github account.

1. Print your public SSH key `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
2. Copy the output
3. Go to your github account setting. Select SSH Keys from Personal settings.
4. Select new SSH Key and paste the output of `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. You can give some name to remember the computer name.

Answer (score 0):

#### Oh-my-zsh method:

If using oh-my-zsh you can use the ssh-agent plugin to manage you SSH connection for you.

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/ssh-agent

1. You'll want to edit `~/.zshrc`
2. add `ssh-agent` to your plugins list - plugins should be seperated by spaces **not** commas | **e.g** `plugins=(git ssh-agent)`
3. Add [agent-forwarding](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/) and setup your key identities, referencing your private key. These should be added above this line: `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` | **[Reference](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/ssh-agent#instructions)**
4. `$ source ~/.zshrc` to reload your zshrc config file
5. Confirm the identified key is available to ssh-agent `$ ssh-add -l`

Provided the key you identified in your `~/.zshrc` file has been [added](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) to github, you will be able to connect via SSH to github.

### Keychain method:

1. `ssh-add ~/.ssh/PATH_TO_YOUR_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` (e.g. ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
2. Add the following in `~/.ssh/config` - `$ open ~/.ssh/config`

```
Host * 
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile PATH_TO_YOUR_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY (e.g. ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

The `AddKeysToAgent` and `UserKeychain` params will ensure that the key is stored in keychain and made available to ssh-agent

3. Restart your terminal
4. Confirm the identified key is available to ssh-agent `$ ssh-add -l`

Provided the key you identified in your `~/.ssh/config` file has been [added](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) to github, you will be able to connect via SSH to github.